# How to get the message out of an exception in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have some MVC code:

```
throw new HttpException(403, "my error text", new Exception("Show me this message"));
```

In javascript I have a function:

```
changeTextFormat = function (data) {

alert(data.responseText);
alert(data.status);
}
```

There is a lot of info in the `responseText` but what I'm wanting to get access to is `"my error text"` or `"Show me this message"`.

Can anybody tell me how to get this out of the `responseText`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the message if you use the following arguments for your error handling method:

```
function (request, statusText, errorMsg) {
    // use errorMsg to get only the exception message
});
```

If you are using `$.post()` you can define it this way:

```
$.post(url, data, function (data) { 
    ... success callback ... 
}).error(function (request, statusText, errorMessage) {...});
```

or if your calling your action method via the Ajax helper by defining the `OnFailure` property:

```
// javascript
var handleError = function (request, statusText, errorMsg) { ... };

// view
@Ajax.BeginForm(..., new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "handleError" })
```

Answer (score -3):

I recommend you use the JSON to show the exception.

```
{"error":"my error text","message":"Show me this message"}
```

And then parse it:

```
function getData(data){
data=JSON.parse(data);
var error=data.error;
var message=message.message;
}
```